# Perl scripts can't be run from an alias

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, perl, alias

I created the following Alias in httpd.conf:

```
alias /aliasedfolder /some/location/on/the/server/folder
<Location /aliasedfolder>
  AddHandler cgi-script .pl
  Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  AllowOverride None
</Location>
```

The problem is that i can view images within "aliasedfolder" but i am getting a "file does not exist" error when i run a perl script there, e.g. /aliasedfolder/script.pl.

The physical perl script exist in "/some/location/on/the/server/folder".

I made sure the script has 755 permission.

Below is the contents of the perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use CGI qw/:standard/;
print "Content-type:text/html;\n\n";
print "Hello world";
1;
```

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Forget about the logfiles (can't delete the comment).

Comment: What is your documentroot ?
And "/some/location/on/the/server/folder" is an absolute or a relative (to documentroot) path ?

Comment: I see that this has been solved but shouldn't you be using "ScriptAlias" anyway?

Answer (score 1):

After checking the ownership of /some/location/on/the/server/folder, I found out that the owner is the "root" username, whileas I was trying to access the folder through an account (domain name) on Apache that has a different username, e.g. domain.com/aliasedfolder/script.pl

The suexec mechanism is preventing this as a security feature. So, I changed the ownership of the /some/location/on/the/server/folder and the script.pl file inside it from "root" to my account's username and group, and it is working now.

This will prevent other domains pointing to my server from accessing this file (script.pl), as suexec prevents a single file to be shared by multiple domains (which have different usernames).

I can disable the suexec mechanism altogether, but I was advised not to do so due to security concerns.

Thanks for all who tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a

```
<Directory "/some/location/on/the/server/folder" >
    AddHandler cgi-script .pl
    ....
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

Also are you running any security measures, such as [suExec](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/suexec.html) or [SELinux](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux), if you are there are additional ownership and extended attributes tweaks required for your scripts.

Comment: Tried it, but it didn't work.